# Detect when user left viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have controller (news screen), and i need to detect when user leave it. I tried

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

, but the problem is, when user tap share button (share in social networks etc.) that method triggers, but after sharing user is still in news screen, therefore its not work.

I also tried

```
-(void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
```

, but it also trigger when user first enter controller, which is wrong (i need to detect leaving only).

How can i detect when user leave controller, but not trigger when he enter "sharing" pop screen?

Comment: How are you sharing? can you put the code, that will help us to know..

Comment: @iphonic with UIActivityViewController that use standard libs for sharing (fb, vk, twitter, mail etc.)

Comment: I think you can assume leaving as soon as you click on share and present the UIActivityViewController, and in the completion you can handle return back?

Comment: @iphonic it creates additional complecity, besides, i need too much callbacks (when user decide to share news or not, if there are error etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this it will help you.

```
UIActivityViewController *conroller=[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Hello"] applicationActivities:nil];
```

You can handle the sharing thing in the completion here

```
[conroller setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError){
      if(!activityError)
         NSLog(@"Shared");
}];
```

The completion will tell you that the activity was presented so you can handle the activities you want to handle in the completion like this

```
[self presentViewController:conroller animated:YES completion:^{
       NSLog(@"Activity Appeared"); //Same as viewWillDisappear
}];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> These four methods can be used in a view controller's appearance callbacks to determine if it is being presented, dismissed, or added or removed as a child view controller. For example, a view controller can check if it is disappearing because it was dismissed or popped by asking itself in its viewWillDisappear:
>    **method by checking the expression ([self isBeingDismissed] || [self isMovingFromParentViewController]).**

```
- (BOOL)isBeingPresented NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

- (BOOL)isMovingToParentViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (BOOL)isMovingFromParentViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

---

use `isMovingFromParentViewController` for your scenario

```
 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
       [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

       if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController){ 

       }
  }
```

Comment: @El Captain v2.0 thank you, but with your code block inside if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController){ 

       } is never called

Comment: isMovingFromParentViewController returns true if the view controller is disappearing because it was removed from a container view controller, otherwise false. [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621365-ismovingfromparentviewcontroller)

Comment: This won't work as UIActivityViewController are presented in different way.

Comment: I think OP wants to know when viewcontroller dismissed from hierarchy ... not when share presents @iphonic .. may be .... :)

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 yes indeed, however , its not work ((

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban it works for me in one of my project .... but not sure why it wont work for UIActivityViewController ..

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 it not work in any case (even pressing back button)

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 reference please